# Bad Decrypt OpenSSL

Tags: java, linux, encryption, cryptography, encryption-symmetric

I am using Java Program to encrypt the data and sending the encrypted data to Linux machine where data should be decrypted back to original text using OpenSSL.

If i do encryption and decryption in Java Program, it is working fine. But on Linux machine,data is not getting decrypted.

 I m getting below exception:

**bad decrypt
140209007396768:error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length:evp_enc.c:597:**
.
Below is my Java Code:

```
public class EncryptionTest{
Cipher c;
static SecretKey  secKey;
static IvParameterSpec iv;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    KeyGenerator keygen=KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
    secKey=keygen.generateKey();
    byte[] encoded = secKey.getEncoded();

    String KeyString=bytesToHex(encoded);
    System.out.println(KeyString);

    SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();
    iv = new IvParameterSpec(rnd.generateSeed(8));


    byte[] ivencoded=iv.getIV();
    String ivString=bytesToHex(ivencoded);

    System.out.println(ivString);

    new EncryptionTest().start();

}
// encoded the key to hex so that i can use at Linux machine to decrypt the data.
public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
        int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}

public void start() throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("Encryption/Decryption App");

    c = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");


    String input ="Data to be ecrypted";

    byte[] text = input.getBytes();

    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");

    System.out.println("Text : " + new String(text));

    byte[] textEncrypted = encrypt(text, c);


    String encryptedString=bytesToHex(textEncrypted);

    System.out.println("Text Encrypted : " + encryptedString);

    byte[] textDecrypted = decrypt(textEncrypted, c);

    System.out.println("Text Decrypted : " + new String(textDecrypted));

    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
   }

public byte[] encrypt(byte[] b, Cipher c) throws Exception
{
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secKey,iv);
    byte[] encryptedText = null;
    try {
        encryptedText = c.doFinal(b);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR - error occured");
        System.exit(0);
    } 
    return encryptedText;
}

public byte[] decrypt(byte[] b, Cipher c) throws Exception
{
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secKey,iv);

    byte[] decryptedText = c.doFinal(b);
    return decryptedText;
} 
}
```

**At Linux Machine:**
openssl enc -des-cbc -d -in test.txt -out received.txt -iv "ivKeyGenerated from Java" -K "key Generated from Java"

**But Decryption is not getting happened at Linux machine.
Please suggest where i am doing wrong.**

Comment: Did you convert your ciphertext to binary before decrypting?

Comment: What is the error message you get when you try to decrypt the file?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes .. No i did not convert ciphertext to binary before decrypting. I will give a try ..

Comment: @JonathanRosenne .. I am getting error message : bad decrypt 140209007396768:error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length:evp_enc.c:597: .

Comment: @MaartenBodewes .. Thanks for suggestion. I tried converting ciphertext to binary but still got same error.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes ... I had given a try what u have suggested but no luck. Now from Java App i have saved the binary data of the encrypted string in a file and sent the same file to Linux Machine and there when i try to decrypt , i got below error :   bad decrypt
139807646291872:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:604:

Comment: Please could you show as the file test.txt in hex, for example by using the Notepad++ ASCII to HEX converter.